# PHP Nested list from a text file

Tags: php, file

I have textfile "animals.txt" which looks like:

```
mammals     cat, fox, horse
birds       parrot, eagle
reptiles    snake, crocodile
```

Columns are separated with `\t` and `,`.

How can I display it as nested list looking like this:

```
<ul>
        <li>mammals
            <ul>
                <li>cat</li>
                <li>fox</li>
                <li>horse</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>birds
            <ul>
                <li>parrot</li>
                <li>eagle</li>
            </ul>

        </li>
        <li>reptiles
            <ul>
                <li>snake</li>
                <li>crocodile</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

What I have now:

```
$data = file_get_contents('animals.txt');
$array = explode("\t", $data);
foreach ($array as $line) {
    echo "<li>$line</li>";
}
```

Comment: you have to explode `$line` as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work. Exploding each line and then printing the corresponding ul's and li's:

```
$file = file('animals.txt');

print '<ul>';

foreach ($file as $line) {

    // 1) exploding by "\t" and then again by ","
    $values = explode("\t", $line);
    $list = explode(',', $values[1]);

    // 2) show the first name in the line
    print '<li>';   
    print $values[0];
    print '<ul>';

    // 3) followed by a nested ul containing the comma-separated values
    foreach ($list as $sub_item) {  
        print '<li>' . $sub_item . '</li>'; 
    }

    print '</ul>';  
    print '</li>';
}

print '</ul>';
```

Answer (score -1):

This will work. The first step is to separate values that are tab delimited(mammals     cat, fox, horse) and second step(foreach loop) is to get comma delimited values(cat, fox, horse). Finally we are printing individual values in a list(cat fox etc).

```
echo "<ul>";
     $array = explode("\t", $data);
     echo "<li>".$array[0];
        foreach ($array[1] as $line) {
            $values = explode(",",$line)
            echo "<ul>"
            foreach ($values as $val) {
                 echo "<li>$val</li>";
            }
           echo "<.ul>"
        }
    echo "</li>";
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) out of the code really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: It's much better than earlier, but it still doesn't work exactly as I need it to - it isn't nested, and for example "horse" is in the same line with "birds"

Comment: There is still something not ok with that: "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()", but the code from CJ Nimes works :) thanks for help anyway :)